# escaping Postgresql hstore type with ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, hstore

I'm using postgresql type hstore with rails (pg gem). What I need is mass-insert hstore values in lots of rows, so I want to make SQL string.

But I cannot find hstore quoting method in pg gem (I thought there should be one).

Am I missing something, or I should write this quotation method by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use the [`hstore(text, text)` and `hstore(text[], text[])` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) instead of trying to build the string versions. Combine those with the [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) syntax and you'd only be dealing with string literals. For example, if your `hstore` is a single key and value, then:

```
insert into your_table (hstore_column)
values (hstore('key', 'value'))
```

will work and give you `"key"=>"value"` in `hstore_column`; if your `hstore` has multiple pairs then:

```
insert into your_table (hstore_column)
values (hstore(array['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], array['value1, 'value2', 'value3']))
```

will give you `"key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2","key3"=>"value3"` in `hstore_column`.

I doubt the overhead of calling the functions will be much different than the overhead of parsing the string versions.